# Non deducible context in template region

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrap {
  Wrap(T *p) {}
};

#ifdef TEMPLATE
template<typename T>
void foo (Wrap<T> t) {}  // version-1

#else
void foo (Wrap<int> p) {} // version-2
#endif

int main () {
  foo(new int);
}
```

When the `#else` part is compiled, the compilation goes fine and the version-2 is selected. If I try to compile `#ifdef` part, I expect that the version-1 should be selected. However compiler gives error as,

> error: no matching function for call to `foo(int*)'

Am I touching the non-deducible part of `template foo` ? If yes, then can anyone clarify what is the exact rule of **non-deducible** region ?

Answer (score 3):

The type of an class template cannot be determined from arguments passed to its constructor. To know which constructors are available, the compiler must have already chosen which `Wrap` to instantiate.

In the `#else` block you have explicitly chosen to instantiate `Wrap<int>`, so the compiler knows to use the implicit `Wrap<int>(int*)` constructor.

---

Perhaps informally: a type is not deducible, if deducing it presupposes knowing what the to-be-deduced type is.