# function overloading for specific type list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

I'm trying to write some adapter code for type list. Below is an experimental code for the purpose:

```
struct null
{
};

template<typename first, typename second>
struct cell
{
    typedef first head;
    typedef second tail;
};

template <
    typename T1 = null, typename T2 = null, typename T3 = null,
    typename T4 = null, typename T5 = null, typename T6 = null,
    typename T7 = null, typename T8 = null, typename T9 = null,
    typename T10 = null, typename T11 = null, typename T12 = null,
    typename T13 = null, typename T14 = null, typename T15 = null,
    typename T16 = null, typename T17 = null, typename T18 = null
>
struct type_list
{
private:
    typedef typename type_list <
        T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10,
        T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18
    >::type tail;

public:
    typedef cell<T1, tail> type;
};

template<>
struct type_list<>
{
    typedef null type;
};

template<typename T>
void test(T);

#include <cstdio>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void test(typename type_list<T1, T2>::type)
{
    // won't be instantiated
    printf("type_list<T1, T2>::type\n");
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void test(cell<T1, cell<T2, null>>)
{
    printf("cell<T1, cell<T2, null>>\n");
}

int main()
{
    // Below causes compile error when 'void test(cell<T1, cell<T2, null>>)' is absence
    test(type_list<int, int>::type());
}
```

output:

```
cell<T1, cell<T2, null>>
```

I want to use `void test(type_list<T1, T2>::type)` rather than `void test(cell<T1, cell<T2, null>>)` because the former is little bit more concise. My question is

- What's the specific reason that I can't use the former one?
- Is there any workaround? (except using `cell` directly :( )

Of course, type_list is just wrapper for type list generation, so 'just erase `::type` after the `type_list<blah>`' can't be an option.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non deducible context in template region](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397709/non-deducible-context-in-template-region)

Comment: While it's true that the problem at hand is a non-deducible context, and that the suggested duplicate is about a non-deducible context, the two situations aren't exactly the same. There has to be a better match.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of:

```
template<typename T>
void test(T);
```

causes it to be the best match for your function call (until you put in the cell overload). Try changing your function call to:

```
test<int,int>(type_list<int, int>::type());
```